# Is it possible to link to an element within an element?

Tags: html, url, anchor, element

Is it possible to link to an Element Id within a container that already has an element id?

My setup is that I have Tabs which have an element id, we use this to link our customers to open this tab. Within the tabs, we have accordions. Basically it is a FAQ section for different types, and each type has a huge list of FAQS which we categorise.

Currently, we are able to link customers to `#type1` but cannot link `#type1#faq1`.

What we are trying to achieve is to give the customer a HTML URL link which opens up a tab, then opens up the FAQ accordion which has for this example an element id of `#faq1`.

Comment: Do you open the tab with CSS or with JavaScript? And can you [edit] the question to include a (minimal) example that shows how you do it?

Comment: Hello, it opens with JS, but the whole thing was in shambles when you have elements within elements, so instead, we just create element id's but had direct text link anchors that would scroll down.

Still worked with the URL, but didn't have to go nuts on the id's.